# How can renders be matched up in Blender?

Tags: rendering

What is the best way to set up rendering in Blender so the images come out at the exact same position and size as another program?

For example, I have a series of color renders from Maya and want to add a pass with just line art from Blender. How can I match up the two in Blender?

Comment: you need to research the aspect ratios for the cameras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would setup a [background image](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View_Options#Background_Image). By setting the axis to camera you will always see the image or movie while looking in camera view <kbd>Numpad-0</kbd>. If you select a movie it will change as you change the current frame in blender allowing you to follow the animation.

You will most likely want to ensure that the render settings match the original video so that there is no distortion or misplacement. You can also choose whether the image shows up in front of or behind your models.

This is a viewport only display, the image will not be included in the final render, you will need to composite it over the video.